# 2nd Order Differential Equation, particular integral query.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

What would the form of the particular integral be of the following differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} -4 \frac{dy}{dx} +5y=8 \sin x$$

Should the particular integral be of the form; $$y_p=ax\cos x$$

Because the complementary function is of the form; $$y_c=A\sin x +B\cos x$$

Cheers.

Gurjinder.B

I do apologise in advance if this question seems very obvious.

Comment: @Travis Sorry, corrected.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial has real roots, I think the complementary solution will involve exponentials not trig functions.

Comment: @AydinGerek Sorry, question edited, should be $5y$

Comment: Then the particular solution ought to be of the form $ax \cos x + bx \sin x$. See [the method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for the use of differential operators here.

To find $y_c$ by the following:

$m^2-4m+5=0$

Completing the square gives something as $y_c=2±i$

Hence $y_c=e^{2x}[A\cos x+B\sin x]$

Finding$y_p$ by method of differential operators

$y_p=8[\frac{\sin x}{D^2-4D+5}]$

=$8[\frac{\sin x}{4-4D}]$

Using the conjugate of $4-4D$

=$8[\frac{(4+4D)\sin x}{16-16D^2}]$

=$8[\frac{4\sin x+4\cos x}{32}]$

Hence, $y_p=\sin x+\cos x$

Hence can find general solution.

Comment: Cheers, will look this method up.